# tricky static generic method with generic return type which itself could be a generic

Tags: java, generics

I have a class as follows:

```
public class MyConverter {
    public <T> T convert (Object o, String typeidentifier, T dummy)
    {
         ... do some conversions such as a java array to an ArrayList or vice versa
         ... based on a typeidentifier syntax similar to Class.getName() but which
         ... embeds information about generic subtypes
    }
}
```

and want to be able to do something general like this:

```
int[] ar = {...};
ArrayList<Integer> dummy = null;
Integer elem = MyConverter.convert(ar, "java.util.ArrayList<Integer>", dummy)
                  .get(15);
```

That is, the `T` in convert may itself be a generic instance, and I found that to get this goal to work, I have to pass a fully typed dummy, as `ArrayList.class` won't give the java compiler enough information that it is an `ArrayList<Integer>` if I used `Class<T> dummycls` instead of `T dummy`.

Am I missing something?  Is there a way to both write and invoke convert without requiring a dummy?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  It seems to be over complicated.

Comment: You want to for something like `ArrayList<Integer>.class`? You can use a cast: `(Class<ArrayList<Integer>>)(Object)ArrayList.class`. Though, it doesn't look too elegant either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specify the type on your call, rather than letting java infer the type:

```
Integer elem = MyConverter.<ArrayList<Integer>>convert(ar, "java.util.ArrayList<Integer>");
```

[This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) describes this (cool) syntax.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Where is it documented on oracle's site?

Comment: I added a link that describes it. fyi, I stumbled on to this little-known syntax when using Eclipse to in-line a result variable (which then removed any chance for java to infer the type) and Eclipse inserted the type using this syntax. Needless to say, I struck generics gold and have used this often since. It's much nicer than passing in a class *just* to lock in the type.

Answer (score 7):

This kind of looks like Arrays.asList, it will take a native array and convert it to an ArrayList.

An implementation could like the following:

```
 public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    ArrayList<T> arr = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T item: a) {
        arr.add(item);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I agree, the Arrays.asList method looks like what you'd want to use.

Comment: I'm doing way more in my convert function than just ArrayList conversions.  Also, HashMap conversions and other intricate things.  I need the other answers more general method.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the logic whatever you want to convert in convert method and cast it to generic type and return.

```
   public class MyConverter {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Integer i = MyConverter.convert();
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        private static <T> T convert() {
            Integer i = new Integer(10);
            return (T)i;
        }
    }
```